# Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I have an PopCorn Ketentuan Library, where i need to populate it with some old data we have on csv file. so i did the following:-

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Read the CSV file
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path "C:\_MSI\IPPS\deploy\Final Upload POPCORN 15 Agustus 2023Test.csv"
 
#If the CSV Doesn't has column Headers, you can create Named Headers
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path "C:\_MSI\IPPS\deploy\Final Upload POPCORN 15 Agustus 2023Test.csv" -Header("ID","TglBerlaku","NomorRegistrasi", "Status", "ViewCount", "Name", "GroupOwner", "CertainGroup", "CertainPeople", "NamaKetentuan","TglUpload", "JenisKetentuan", "Bahasa", "ID CHIPS", "IsPublished", "NomorRegistrasiReff", "Kodefikasi", "TipeKetentuan", "DownloadCount", "ItemType", "Path")
 
#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://rvssima1wbc19wd:15628/sites/popcorn_dev"
 
#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["PopCorn Ketentuan"]
 
#Iterate through each Row in the CSV
foreach ($row in $CSVData)
 {
   $item = $list.AddItem();
    
   $item["ID"] = $row.ID
   $item["Tgl Berlaku"] = Get-Date $row.TglBerlaku
   $item["Nomor Registrasi"] = $row.NomorRegistrasi
   $item["Status"] = $row.Status
   $item["View Count"] = $row.ViewCount
   $item["Name"] = $row.Name
   $item["Group Owner"] = $row.GroupOwner
   $item["Certain Group"] = $row.CertainGroup
   $item["Certain People"] = $row.CertainPeople
   $item["Nama Ketentuan"] = $row.NamaKetentuan
   $item["Tgl Upload"] = Get-Date $row.TglUpload
   $item["Jenis Ketentuan"] = $row.JenisKetentuan
   $item["Bahasa"] = $row.Bahasa
   $item["ID CHIPS"] = $row.IDCHIPS
   $item["Is Published"] = $row.IsPublished
   $item["Nomor Registrasi Reff"] = $row.NomorRegistrasiReff
   $item["Kodefikasi"] = $row.Kodefikas
   $item["Tipe Ketentuan"] = $row.TipeKetentuan
   $item["Download Count"] = $row.DonwloadCount
   $item["Item Type"] = $row.ItemType
   $item["Path"] = $row.Path

 
   #Set the People Picker Field value
   #$item["Assigned To"] = Get-SPUser -Identity $row.AssignedTo -web "https://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Marketing/"
     
   #Set the Date Field value
   #$item["Due Date"] = Get-Date $row.DueDate
 
   #$item["Status"] = $row.Status
   $item.Update()
 }
```

but i got this error :-

```
    This field cannot be updated.
At line:20 char:4
+    $item["ID"] = $row.ID
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException
 
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type 
"System.DateTime"."
At line:21 char:36
+    $item["Tgl Berlaku"] = Get-Date $row.TglBerlaku
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
 
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type 
"System.DateTime"."
At line:30 char:35
+    $item["Tgl Upload"] = Get-Date $row.TglUpload
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
 
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()"
At line:50 char:4
+    $item.Update()
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException
```

so can anyone advice on this please?